# How to read /dev/input/eventX

Tags: linux, events, devise, keyboard-events, input-devices

I want to read input-data (keyboard-input) from the /dev/input/eventX-Files. I thought, I find the informations in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 19. Feb 07:45 usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-if01 -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 19. Feb 07:45 usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event3
```

But when I read the events, they are empty. The date and time of the files (read with ls -l) suggest that they does not have changed since system boot.

Can somebody tell me how to get such informations like keyboard-input.

Gruß, Andre

Solution: 
When I was logged in as root today it worked, I could read the input from the keyboard.

Comment: data read from these special files are structs of type input_event, defined in linux/input.h, and documented in [input/input.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt).

Comment: the question is not clear. i guess "access permission" is a better title than "how to" if it is what OP means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: When I was logged in as root today it worked, I could read the /dev/input/event*-device.

So it was a permission-issue.